# Emacs org-mode file/viewer associations

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In an Emacs org-mode file, when I click on a PDF the file opens in a PDF viewer.  Similarly, when I click on a URL it opens in a web browser.  But when I click on a path to an image file, the byte stream opens as text in the editor.  How do I configure Emacs/org-mode to open images with a specified application, say an image editor or a browser?

Comment: FYI, Emacs is (in theory) able to display images itself. http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Images.html

Comment: @phils try `org-display-inline-images'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In org-mode, this is `org-file-apps` that control what to do when clicking on a URL-like text.

It is configured by default to :

```lisp
((auto-mode . emacs)
 ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
 ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
 ("\\.pdf\\'" . default))
```

As said in org-file-apps help : `auto-mode` matches files that are matched by any entry in `auto-mode-alist`, so all files Emacs knows how to handle.  Using this with command `emacs` will open most files in Emacs.

You may have image file extension configured in auto-mode-alist. You could override this alist by doing something like this in your .emacs (for example, for png files) :

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
             (setq org-file-apps
                   (append '(
                             ("\\.png\\'" . default)
                             ) org-file-apps ))))
```

With this code, when I click on a link like this :

```
file:///e:/jrx/emacs/image.png
```

It opens the file outside emacs, using the default OS program associated to this file extension.

You don't have to change `org-file-apps-defaults-windowsnt`, `org-file-apps-defaults-gnu` or `org-file-apps-defaults-macosx` to use the OS default program associated to the file extension.

Comment: Using `append` together with `add-hook 'org-mode-hook` seems to append to the list whenever Org-mode is invoked. This can flood the list with `"\\.png\\'" . default`. You might be better of using a `add-to-list` construct such as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8836108/789593 instead.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on what operating system you use, but it should be configurable with `org-file-apps`.

- On OS X, I would use `open` (or `open -a Application.app`) for opening files automagically
- On Linux/BSD etc, I would use `xdg-open` (a bit tricky to setup, tho)
- On windows, I guess I would use `open` (in the console)

Look at the variables `org-file-apps-defaults-windowsnt`, `org-file-apps-defaults-gnu` or `org-file-apps-defaults-macosx` depending on your plattform.

Comment: linking to https://askubuntu.com/questions/646631/emacs-doesnot-work-with-xdg-open for people struggling with `xdg-open` :)