# Org-mode does not open PDFs in Evince even when org-file-apps is seemingly properly set

Tags: pdf, emacs, org-mode

A few years ago I started using Org-mode for taking notes on PDFs. I used one of the solutions in [How do I make Org-mode open PDF files in Evince?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834633/how-do-i-make-org-mode-open-pdf-files-in-evince) to make Org-mode open PDF files in Evince; I used the following in my .emacs :

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
    '(lambda ()
        (delete '("\\.pdf\\'" . default) org-file-apps)
        (add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.pdf\\'" . "evince %s"))))
```

I've returned to my .org file ater a year or so. Most probably my org-mode updated (it's 8.2.10 now) and the solution above no longer works -- Emacs itself opens the PDFs. What should I do?

What's troubling me additionally is that literally the first example in the documentation for org-file-apps is

```
                 Example: ("pdf" . "evince %s")
                      to open PDFs with evince.
```

However, I tried

```
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
    '(lambda ()
        (delete '("\\.pdf\\'" . default) org-file-apps)
        (add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("pdf" . "evince %s"))))
```

and it still does not work -- the PDF is opened in an Emacs buffer.

The value of org-file-apps is:

```
 (("pdf" . "evince %s")
  (auto-mode . emacs)
  ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
  ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default))
```

Evince *is* installed :-) I'm using Emacs 24.5.1 on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. What should I do?

Comment: The original solution *should* still work. Your later attempts suffer from various defects (e.g. the pdf value in `org-file-apps` should read `("\\.pdf\\'" . "evince %s")` ), but whether it "works" or not depends on how you open the file: if you have a link in an org file pointing to the PDF and you click on the link, it *will* open in evince. With `C-x C-f` however, org is out of the picture: emacs is in charge and it uses Document View.

Comment: @Nick Thanks! Your remark about `C-x C-f` was very useful to me; I'm using a way of generating and opening links described here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex-devel/2012-10/msg00005.html which uses `find-file`. I decided to go with `openwith`, then (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/how-to-use-an-external-program-as-the-default-way-to-open-pdfs-from-emacs ). I have no idea about:
1) why the method I was using worked before, since it used `findfile`;
2) why you'd say using `("pdf" . "evince %s")` was defective (it's lifted straight from the docs).
Thanks again!

Comment: Look at the difference in the pattern. Try with a text file called "pdffile.txt" e.g. If I've got it right, org-open-at-point will try to open it with evince - not sure what will happen next :-)